# Creating a horizontal, reusable "cell" inside a UIScrollView

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, pagination

I'm wanting to create something that moves akin to Springboard, so a paginated UIScrollView with multiple pages (depending on the number of results returned via an XML query). Effectively similar to [this Apple example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html).

Each page will have the same layout, but will be populated with different data (so an image, labels, etc.)

I'm relatively new to iOS development, is there a way to design a cell for this in the same way I'd design a custom UITableViewCell? I realise that UITableView inherits from UIScrollView anyway, but I've never heard of a UIScrollViewCell or similar. I'm falling at the early stage of planning out the way to approach the problem. Ideally it could re-use the cell in the same way a TableView can dequeue them.

Any hints on what to begin thinking about? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UIScrollView` does not provide something like the cells of a `UITableView`, it is much more basic than the table view. In contrast to a table view you have to add to the `UIScrollView` and arrange them yourself.

If you may develop for iOS 6 only, you might want to take a look at `UICollectionView`.

```
Collection views provide the same general function as table views except that a collection view is able to support more than just single-column layouts.
```

If you want to support other iOS versions than iOS 6, you might find something useful at http://www.cocoacontrols.com.